# Receiving voice input from an Android wearable emulator

Tags: android, wear-os

How do we receive voice input from an Android wearable emulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voice input is disabled in the Android Wear preview emulator image.

The voice engine just returns a string, so you could use that for testing purposes. Thanks, +Ali Naddaf.

Comment: You can, however, type in your message for testing purposes.

Comment: How can you type in messages? I can not get my keyboard to work in the emulator. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @ Glenn Bech type it on your mac keyboard.

Comment: Just type from your physical keyboard mate!

Comment: I can only type numbers on keyboard. Is that normal?