# Is there any way to add google TTS engine in android wear simulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, simulator, android-wear-2.0

I have ASUS Zenwatch2 which has inbuilt google TTS, but unfortunately it got damage. So I have tried to create simulator in Android studio but there is no option to add TTS engine.Is there any way i can get same hardware profile as ASUS Zenwatch2 in simulator as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if this in now applicable but it is stated in this SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24597164/5995040) that android emulator does not support voice input and real device is needed to test it. According to this [blog](https://www.engadget.com/2016/02/04/android-wear-update-gestures-voice-messages) that talks about the update of android wear on adding voice control. You may also want to check [Adding Voice Capabilities](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html) on how to implement voice capabilities in your wear app.

Comment: Now with latest wear emulator you can give input through voice just make sure your wearable emulator is paired with phone